# Gradle: how does one modify a dynamically created task?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am building an Android Library project using the Android Gradle plugin (version 0.9.2) and it appears to have a bug (reported) in that while a "provided" dependency is correctly handled  (not included) in the generated aar artifact, that dependency is incorrectly included in the generated debug test apk file.

It strikes me that a reasonable workaround is to remove the dependency jar file that is added by the :preDexDebugTest task as the last step for that task.  But this task is dynamically generated so getting a handle to it is eluding me at the moment, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your app's `build.gradle` file, add

```
afterEvaluate {
    def preDexDebugTest = tasks['preDexDebugTest']

    // Do something with preDexDebugTest ...
}
```

That way it should be possible to operate on the `preDexDebugTest` task.